# Compare Columns on different Workbooks and copy from one to the other

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT: Am I required to use the object model?

So I am having trouble with this program. I have written a GUI that has two list boxes and some buttons. I am trying to start the program, select a column of data/numbers to compare with another column of data/numbers on another worksheet and then copy the adjacent cells of the first to one specified in the program. The copy part of my code worked fine along but when I added all the sheet stuff in it quit working. I don't Know if it is because you can't compare on two sheets after you do a .Active/.Open or if I plain don't understand .Active and .Open. If I am doing something wrong, I don't have a clue how to fix it. Any Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Nick

P.S I have included only the part of the code where I think there is a problem. If needed I can submit the whole thing.

```
Sub copy2()

 Dim ColCopyTo As String 'the column you want to copy to
  Dim ColSelect As String 'the column with the initial data
  Dim ColCompare 'the column you want to compare the initial data with
  Dim ColCopyFrom 'the column you want to copy data from
  Dim RowCrntCompare As Long
  Dim RowCrntSelect As Long
  Dim RowLastColCompare As Long
  Dim RowLastColSelect As Long
  Dim SelectValue As String
  Dim WorkSheetSelect As Worksheet 'the worksheet with initial data
  Dim WorkSheetCompare As Worksheet ' the worksheet you want to compare initial data on
  Dim WorkBookCompare As Workbook 'the workbook you want to compare initial data on
  Dim WorkBookSelect As Workbook ' the workbook with initial data on it
  Dim WorkSheetIndex As Integer

  With Sheet1

    continue = False 'initialise continue to false
    MsgBox "Select the Workbook and Worksheet"
    CommandButton2.Visible = True
    CommandButton1.Visible = False

    Call Wait 'pause until button is clicked

    'MsgBox ListBox2.value

    WorkSheetIndex = udfSheetIndex(ListBox2.value) 'index of the worksheet
    'MsgBox WorkSheetIndex

   'Set WorkBookSelect = Workbooks(ListBox1.value)
    Set WorkBookSelect = Workbooks.Open(ListBox1.value)
    WorkBookSelect.Activate
    Set WorkSheetSelect = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WorkSheetIndex)

    'Set WorkBookCompare = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WorkSheetSelect)
    'WorkBookSelect.Activate ' set the initial workbook to active

    WorkSheetSelect.Activate ' set the initial worksheet to active
    ColSelect = InputBox("which column do you want to select From") 'column you want to first select for copying
    ColCopyFrom = InputBox("which column do you want to copy data ColCopyFrom") 'where you are copying data from

    continue = False 'reset continue to false
    MsgBox "select the workbook and worksheet you want to compare to"
    CommandButton2.Visible = True
    Call Wait 'wait for button click
    'Set WorkBookCompare = Workbooks(ListBox1.value)
    Set WorkBookCompare = Workbooks.Open(ListBox1.value)
    WorkBookCompare.Activate
    MsgBox ListBox2.value
    WorkSheetIndex = udfSheetIndex(ListBox2.value) 'index of the worksheet
    MsgBox "listbox2" & ListBox2.value
    MsgBox WorkSheetIndex
    Set WorkSheetCompare = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WorkSheetIndex)
    WorkBookCompare.Activate 'set the second workbook to active
    WorkSheetCompare.Activate ' set the second worksheet to active

    ColCompare = InputBox("which column do you want to compare to ") 'the column you are comparing it to
    ColCopyTo = InputBox("which column do you want to copy data to") 'where you are copying data to

    RowLastColSelect = .Range(ColSelect & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'length of the selected column
    RowLastColCompare = .Range(ColCompare & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'length of ColCompare

    For RowCrntSelect = 1 To RowLastColSelect Step 1 ' from 1 to last
      SelectValue = .Cells(RowCrntSelect, ColSelect).value ' value of cell
        'MsgBox SelectValue
      If SelectValue <> "" Then
        For RowCrntCompare = 1 To RowLastColCompare Step 1
          If SelectValue = Cells(RowCrntCompare, ColCompare).value Then
            .Cells(RowCrntCompare, ColCopyTo).value = _
                                           .Cells(RowCrntSelect, ColCopyFrom).value
          End If
        Next RowCrntCompare
      End If
    Next RowCrntSelect

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: tl;dr - can you be more specific with the actual problem? learn to debug your own code

Comment: I have no idea what the actual problem is. It just won't copy when I add in features to copy from one workbook to another. I can't really find anything that has done it before either. I don't think its a debugging issue but I accept your criticism and only ask that if I am missing information that you please direct it my way. But please don't dismiss my problem so quickly as this is my first program with no prior knowledge of VB or VBA. I ask how to fix the problem but I welcome any ADVICE that isn't dismissive.

Answer (score 0):

On your line:

```
WorkSheetIndex = udfSheetIndex(ListBox2.value) 'index of the worksheet
```

try using:

```
WorkSheetIndex = Sheets(ListBox2.value).Index
```

UDF stands for "User Defined Function", so I'm guessing its not working because the function is not set up correctly.

Comment: No, that's not quite it either. My function returns the correct value. I used the function so I could run it on the active sheet so I did 

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Name).index

In the function, and the only reason I put it there was to keep my code tidy. Like I said I don't think I am completely understanding the functionality of VBA especially working with different sheets and books

Comment: @user2939604 Can you post the line on which it fails or at least give us some indication of where the script fails?